# What represents this more exactly

Tags: python, feedparser

I'm building a RSS-Feed parser to extract news from various websites. One thing tho that makes me confused is:

```
<html lang="nl" dir="ltr" prefix="content: http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/  dc: http://purl.org/dc/terms/  foaf: http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/  og: http://ogp.me/ns#  rdfs: http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#  schema: http://schema.org/  sioc: http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#  sioct: http://rdfs.org/sioc/types#  skos: http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#  xsd: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema# " class=" js" data-triggered="true">
```

More exactly: `http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/`. This website is like a documentation of RSS. Does this means that this site has a page of rss or ... ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Haven't used RSS in like 15 years or so. But correct me if I'm wrong, that URL you're asking about is just a documentation site for the syntax used in the actual feed (which should be an XML stream). But it doesn't automatically ensure that there's a RSS feed anywhere, but likeliness is high, yes.

Comment: @Torxed It's interesting cause i can't find the rss endpoint for a lot of websites that contain that syntax documentation (neither from body, nor playing with endpoints in url), which is really strange, why would you include that part in the html if you don't have an rss endpoint. Later i'm going to try harder on these sites to maybe find these endpoints.

Comment: Because the TOS probably say that you have to have that documentation somewhere, and that's a good place to put it. The RSS is probably else where and is usually just a button somewhere sadly. Altho, there should be a RSS feed pointer for some automated finders to detect and use. Again, haven't used RSS since the dinosaur age and find them quite clonky these days.